# remix run not executing dynamic route file

Tags: remix.run

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-phuvuy) with an example of the problem.

I have my setup like this:

[image]

I would expect a url like `/posts/something` to execute the `$slug.tsx` file but it is never called and instead a `404 Not found` is returned.

This is my first time using remix but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer in [this post](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/file-conventions/route-files-v2).

All remix's docs are out of date or at least irrelevant with the new scheme.

Comment: I've got the same issue but I have already (from remix template) v2_routeConvention set to true. Actually to make it work I had to comment it out. Not ideal, but it works, hopefully v2 docs will have some more info.

Comment: It would save people a little bit of time if you briefly explained the solution in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

I was also running through the existing "remix blog tutorial" that is linked in the remix.run documentation here: https://remix.run/docs/en/1.15.0/tutorials/blog

Unfortunately, as mentioned previously, **some of the Remix documentation is out-of-date and they don't mention it inside the blog tutorial proper**.

Specifically when you get to the "dynamic routes" section of the tutorial here: https://remix.run/docs/en/1.15.0/tutorials/blog#dynamic-route-params - if you just follow the tutorial step-by-step you'll find that the following code doesn't work with a new installation:

```
touch app/routes/posts/\$slug.tsx

export default function PostSlug() {
  return (
    <main className="mx-auto max-w-4xl">
      <h1 className="my-6 border-b-2 text-center text-3xl">
        Some Post
      </h1>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Here is why:

If you look inside your `remix.config.js` file you'll see the following:

```
module.exports = {
  cacheDirectory: "./node_modules/.cache/remix",
  future: {
    v2_errorBoundary: true,
    v2_meta: true,
    v2_normalizeFormMethod: true,
    v2_routeConvention: true,
  },
  ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/.*", "**/*.css", "**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
};
```

**TAKE PARTICULAR NOTE OF THE STUFF PREFIXED WITH V2_ !! as this is where the tutorial breaks!**

In the case of dynamic routes, the way described in the tutorial won't work with `v2_routeConvention: true` because this is telling your remix app to use the new routing conventions. I would just go ahead and use the V2 routing conventions (as that is where things are ostensibly headed...) which are described here: https://remix.run/docs/en/1.15.0/pages/v2

That section of documentation tells you the specifics that I've outlined in this answer.

These "future flags" in the `remix.config.js` are more targeted at existing applications that are already written in the V1 version of Remix-run and need to be able to migrate their codebase to the new conventions without having to do EVERYTHING at once, and thus, letting remix developers incrementally migrate to the new conventions that will be found in remix V2.

When starting from scratch, as in the case of the blog tutorial, it can be quite confusing because there is no mention to go look at the "Preparing for V2" information (linked above) that talks about these "future flags" and the changes in conventions going into the new V2 version of Remix.

I hope this helps someone who's stuck at the Remix dynamic routing part of building a Remix app to more clearly understand the problem and solution. Remix certainly is a promising and exciting framework for React - it's little details like this that can really turn people off to using it, and perhaps could slow it's adoption to some extent. Now I need to go figure out how to submit recommendations for updating the documentation!

Good luck and code on! #remix #react

Comment: Ironically it's a routing issue as their homepage links you to 
https://remix.run/docs/en/1.15.0/tutorials/blog rather than https://remix.run/docs/en/main/tutorials/blog which is up to date!

Comment: This comment from @Jon.Mozley is the most useful info of all, though this answer is otherwise the best one.

Answer (score 5):

TLDR

1. Rename *$slug.tsx* to *posts.$slug.tsx*
2. Rename *index.tsx* to *posts._index.tsx*
3. Move the two files one directory up into *routes*
4. (optionally) Delete the posts directory

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In `remix.config.js`, remove `v2_routeConvention: true` so remix is not configured to use flat routes.

Comment: I don't think removing is a good idea.  This looks like the way they are heading

Comment: the documentation about v2 dynamic routing seems quite confusing to me, as a matter of fact there's no example of dynamic nested route. Maybe when v2 will be out it'll be better shown.